# Limit Youtube API video by date

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api

Is there a way to limit youtube.playlist_items.list by start-date and end-date?

I would like to only grab videos that we're uploaded in the past day with out having to parse any videos before then.

Currently the path I'm using to pull the videos is:

1. Connect get the playlist id from youtube.channels.list upload
   parameters.
2. I then connect to youtube.playlist_items.list and get the videos and cycle through until next_page_token is nil.

Thank you